# Ido-goto-symbol command support for emacs python mode

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode, ido

The function `ido-goto-symbol` when run in `emacs python mode`, shows the message `No items suitable for an index found in this buffer`. How can I get the `ido-goto-symbol` to work in `python-mode` so that it lists functions and classes present in the python file?

Comment: It does work for me. I took that function from here: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Imenu Where did you take yours from ?

Comment: I took it from emacs wiki, but both the functions are the same.

Comment: What I observed is that `ido-goto-symbol` function does not work in `emacs 23` for python mode (works well for c-mode or html-mode, for example), but works in `emacs 24.2` for python mode as well. I think there is some other basic problem. I started emacs 23 with -q option so that the ido-goto-symbol function is not loaded. Trying the command `M-x imenu RET` still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`M-x imenu RET` provides that functionality already.

Should work with python-mode.el as with shipped python.el

Checked with

GNU Emacs 24.3.90.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.5) of 2014-04-21

In case of trouble start from emacs -Q

Comment: I started `emacs` with `-q` option, so that the `ido-goto-symbol` function is not loaded. Running `M-x imenu RET` still gives the same error `No items suitable for an index found in this buffer`. I am running `emacs 23`. Do I have to install any `emacs python packages` to be able to run the command?